# Access to nested JSON property with vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Does anybody understand why I can't access to a nested JSON attribute with the typical dot notation js access??

I have this JSON object:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "user_id":1,
      "view_id":1,
      "module_id":1,
      "user_module_id":1,
      "is_active":false,
      "view":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"June",
         "module_id":1,
         "is_active":false
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "user_id":1,
      "view_id":2,
      "module_id":1,
      "user_module_id":1,
      "is_active":false,
      "view":{
         "id":2,
         "name":"November",
         "module_id":1,
         "is_active":false
      }
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "user_id":1,
      "view_id":3,
      "module_id":1,
      "user_module_id":1,
      "is_active":false,
      "view":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"March",
         "module_id":1,
         "is_active":true
      }
   }
]
```

And I'm trying to access to the nested property "view.name" with vue.js like this:

```
<template v-for="module_view in module_views">
  <tr>
       <td>{{module_view.view.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

But the console returns me this error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

I don't have problems to access to the 1 level attributes, for example:

```
{{module_view.module_id}} //this works fine!
```

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the error is somewhere else. Because it works for me - http://jsbin.com/mukoliceco/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks I will check my code to search for the error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: try putting just module_view, or console log it.  Perhaps one of the objects in your array is missing the view attribute.

Comment: Solved!! thanks guys!! I'm new with vue.js, my problem was that I've not predefined my JSON properly in the "data" attribute, I've add the view: {}, attribute and its elements predefined in the "data" vue's attribute and now it works!! Thanks a lot.